# Idle timeout Bourne-style shell

Tags: linux, sh, freebsd

Is there any way to timeout idle users in Bourne-style shell (/bin/sh).

man sh does not talk about it.

http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?sh

TIMEOUT or TMOUT shell env variables in /etc/profile works fine for bash and ksh.

http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash

C-Shell has /etc/csh.logout set autologout option.

http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?csh

I don't find any similar option in case of sh (/bin/sh).

## UPDATE:

/bin/sh seems to be reading /etc/profile.

Added following entries in /etc/profile:

```
TMOUT=60
readonly TMOUT
export TMOUT
```

After login:

```
$ env
USER=test
HOME=/var/home/test
LOGNAME=test
TERM=vt100
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/opt/sbin:/opt/bin
SHELL=/bin/sh
TMOUT=60
```

/var/home/test/trace (sh debug logs):

```
token word TMOUT=60
pipeline: entered
reread token word TMOUT=60
reread token word TMOUT=60
reread token word TMOUT=60
reread token word TMOUT=60
reread token word TMOUT=60
reread token word TMOUT=60
token newline
```

But still, idle session does not get auto-logout.
/bin/sh/ does not seem to be using TMOUT value.

Comment: Did you ever find an appropriate solution or alternative workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [doinkd](http://idled.sourceforge.net/) port (`sysutils/doinkd`). From the package description;

> The idle daemon (doinkd) monitors user activity and logs them off when
>   predefined rules are met. These include session time, multiple logins,
>   tty, idletime and group limits. Similar to the Unix idleout command,
>   but much more configurable. Formerly idled.

Comment: unfortunately, I am looking for this feature in 'sh' itself.